# Filter output items of reverse relations in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I have these models:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="books")
    published_at = models.DateField()
```

And this is my query:

```
Author.objects.filter(books__published_at__ragne=[date_from, date_to]).annotate(books_count=Count('books'))
```

The query's output will be sent to below serializer(inherit django rest framework serializer):

```
class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    books_count= serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    books = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'books_count', 'books']
```

The **AuthorSerializer** output will be all authors who have at least one book published in specified range, with the number of books published by each author, and also the string representation of all books of each author.

The `books__published_at__ragne` filter affect output authors and books count, but it won't affect books of authors. I mean for each author, all books are returned, not only books which are published in specified range.

How can i also filter books with that specified parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with a `Prefetch` object:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

Author.objects.filter(
    books__published_at__range=[date_from, date_to]
).annotate(books_count=Count('books')).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'books',
        queryset=Book.objects.filter(published_at__ragne=[date_from, date_to])
    )
)
```

This thus means that `books_count` will determine the number of books published in that range, and the `books` list will also contain only these books.

Comment: ```books_count``` will determine the number of books published in the range anyway. Am i right?

Comment: @AminA2: yes as is specified right below the code fragment. That is also the case in your queryset.

Comment: @AminA2: so the "*with the number of books published by each author*" in your question is not entirely correct: it will count the number of books published in the given datetime range. The `Prefetch` has no impact on the `.annotate(...)` and `.aggregate(..)`s, etc.: since the books are fetched in a second independent query.